# WebServiceException when accessng webservice using Apache CXF generated classes

Tags: web-services, ssl, cxf

I am having problems accessing a web service using Apache CXF generated classes (wsdl2java).

Everything was working fine until the web service provider suddenly changed a rule on their firewall and hosed us. What they are saying is they no longer allow *http* traffic, we have to start using *https*. The funny thing is, up until now we thought we *were* using https. This is inherited, legacy code. But we are pretty much using word for word the ssl example on the Apache CXF web site.

Here's a chunk of the wsdl:

```
...
<wsdl:portType name="GetMessagesSoap">
  <wsdl:operation name="GetInfo">
    <wsdl:input message="tns:GetInfoSoapIn" />
    <wsdl:output message="tns:GetInfoSoapOut" />
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

...

<wsdl:service name="GetMessages">
  <wsdl:port name="GetMessagesSoap" binding="tns:GetMessagesSoap">
    <soap:address location="http://127.0.0.1/GetMessages.asmx" />
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Basically we generate all the Java classes using wsdl2java. Then in our Gateway class we do the following:

```
private GetMessagesSoap getInstance() {
  GetMessages getMessages = new GetMessages(wsdlUrl);
  GetMessagesSoap getMessagesSoap = getMessages.getMessagesSoap();
  setupTransportLayerSecurity(getMessagesSoap);
}

private void setupTransportLayerSecurity(final Object port) {

  HTTPConduit httpConduit =
        (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(port).getConduit();
  TLSClientParameters tlsCP = new TLSClientParameters();

  KeyStore keyStore = ...
  KeyManager[] myKeyManagers = getKeyManagers(keyStore ...
  tlsCP.setKeyManagers(myKeyManagers);
  KeyStore trustStore = ...
  TrustManager[] myTrustStoreKeyManagers = getTrustManagers(trustStore);
  tlsCP.setTrustManagers(myTrustStoreKeyManagers);
  tlsCP.setDisableCNCheck(true);
  tlsCP.setSecureSocketProtocol("SSL");

  httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsCP);
}
```

Then we call getInfo(). This is where the error occurs.

```
public void getInfo() {
  GetMessagesSoap getMessagesSoap = getInstance();
  InfoResponse response = getMessagesSoap.getInfo()
}
```

The error we get is rather generic:

```
  javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
```

The ws provider says it's failing because we're trying to come in using http. All this despite all the fancy SSL stuff we're doing in the setupTransportLayerSecurity() method.

My fundamental doubt in all this is, is that really the reason it's failing? I mean, obviously it started failing when the rule was removed from the firewall. But, what I don't understand is, if the url in the GetMessages service in the wsdl is http, even if I say to use SSL, how in the world is it ever going to use https?

We've put a sniffer on the network and sure enough it's only using http. But ... isn't this normal?? I am by no means a SOAP expert, obviously. Can someone shed some light on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

CXF HttpConduit only uses the TlsClientParameters when the address url is start with https.
Can you change the WSDL file?
If not, you can [change service url at the runtime](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/How-to-change-the-service-URL-at-runtime-td3242927.html).